# react native maps markers dont appear

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-maps

I'm using react-native-maps to render maps and markers, but the markers don't appear.

**package.json**

"react-native-maps": "0.27.1",

"react-native": "0.63.2",

**androidmanifest.xml**

```
<meta-data
     android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
     android:value="GOOGLE_API_KEY"/>
     <uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false"/>
```

**build.gradle**

```
   implementation(project(':react-native-maps')){
       exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-base'
       exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-maps'
   }
   implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.2.1'
   implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
```

**My Code**

```
const mainCoordinates= {
    latitude: -23.588432,
    longitude: -46.630702,
    latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
    longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
  }

<MapView style={styles.map} region={mainCoordinates}>
     <Marker
          coordinate={{
          latitude: -23.5732033,
          longitude: -46.711293,
          }}
          title={'Marcador'}
          description={'Testando o marcador no mapa'}
     />
</MapView>
```

SO, this is my code. I searched on google to find a solution, but I coudknt find anything to solve this problem.

Comment: `const mainCootdinates = {` maybe the spelling here?

Comment: No, I just spelt it wrong here, thanks for your comment, I fixed it.